# The Natural Action of the Fundamental Group $\pi_1(M,p_0)$ on the Universal Covering $\widetilde{M}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, group-actions, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Let $M$ be a **Manifold**, $\pi_1(M,p_0)$ the **Fundamental Group** of $M$ at a base-point $p_0$ and $\widetilde{M}$ the **Universal Covering** of $M$.

Then $\widetilde{M}$ can be defined as follows: $$\widetilde{M}=\{[\alpha]: \alpha:[0,1]\longrightarrow M, \alpha(0)=p_0\}$$ where $[\alpha]=[\beta]$ if and only if $\alpha(1)=\beta(1)$ and $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\beta$.

Let $[c]\in \pi_1(M,p_0)$, then the deck transformation associated to $[c]$ is defined as follows: $$c:\widetilde{M}\longrightarrow \widetilde{M}$$ $$c.[\alpha]:=[\alpha \star c^{-1}]$$
This is the natural action of $\pi_1(M,p_0)$ on $\widetilde{M}$.

Am I right?

Is everything correct?

Is there any mistake?

Comment: It seems all correct.